# How to use Xrm.Navigation in your channel integration framework client applicaion

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-sales

Currently I am working with channel integration framework 1.0.My application is loaded inside Customer service hub/ Sale Hub.
When my application loaded inside my organization it load Microsoft.CIFramework JavaScript api. But Xrm is not loaded. I need to navigate activity task list from my application. Xrm.Navigation.navigateto provide this functionality.

Any cdn or method to load Xrm javascript file.
Or
Any other method to solve my problem